# Compare columns of two different tables and replace specific words in a string R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

can someone give me an advice? i try to compare two columns. One column is a string with a address and the other one is just a table with country names. But some country names are in english, which i want to replace in the german term. I also have the problem, that im very limited about using additional packages since i want to use the script in a database. My code dont really works. It just replaces one row.

**df1**

```
DE
Europa | Deutschland | München
Europa | England     | London
Europa | Germany     | Berlin
Europa | Italy       | Venedig
```

**df2**

```
GE              EN
Deutschland     Germany
Italien         Italy
England         UK
```

**Result: df1**

```
DE
Europa | Deutschland | München
Europa | England     | London
Europa | Deutschland | Berlin
Europa | Italien     | Venedig
```

I tried following code:

```
df1 <- data.frame("DE" = c("Europa | Deutschland | München", "Europa | England | London", "Europa | Germany | Berlin ", "Europa | Italy | Venedig"))
df2 <- data.frame("GE" = c("Deutschland", "Italien", "England"), "EN" = c("Germany", "Italy", "UK"))
df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.character)
df2[] <- lapply(df2, as.character)

for(i in seq_along(df1)) df1$DE <- gsub(df2$EN, df2$GE, df1$DE, fixed = FALSE)
```

Comment: How many columns are in `df1`? It looks like `df1` has three columns but your example shows only one column.

Comment: it just has one column. The words in the string are seperated with a pipeline symbol

Answer (score 1):

You should add `[i]` in the `for` loop and use `fixed = TRUE` as you use fixed pattern and not the regular expressions. Find other modifications in the code:

```
for(i in seq_along(df2$EN)) {
    df1$DE <- gsub(df2$EN[i], df2$GE[i], df1$DE, fixed = TRUE)
}
df1$DE

## [1] "Europa | Deutschland | München"
## [2] "Europa | England | London"     
## [3] "Europa | Deutschland | Berlin "
## [4] "Europa | Italien | Venedig"
```

---

p.s. You can use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `data.frame()` to get strings instead of factors:

```
df1 <- data.frame("DE" = c("Europa | Deutschland | München",
                           "Europa | England | London", 
                           "Europa | Germany | Berlin ",
                           "Europa | Italy | Venedig"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame("GE" = c("Deutschland", "Italien", "England"), 
                  "EN" = c("Germany", "Italy", "UK"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: @yellowdays, is this the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on `merge` and replace. The reason to split the column is I only want to replace the names in the second column. If we use `gsub` with a for-loop, there is a possibility that matching words from other columns may also be replaces. `df4` is the final output.

**Step 1: Separate the column in `df1` by `|`.**

```
df1_1 <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(df1$DE, split = "\\|"), trimws)),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Step 2: Merge `df1_1` and `df2`**

```
df3 <- merge(df1_1, df2, by.x = "V2", by.y = "EN", all.x = TRUE)
```

**Step 3: Replace the values if the `GE` column is not `NA`.**

```
df3$V2 <- ifelse(!is.na(df3$GE), df3$GE, df3$V2)
```

**Step 4: Collapse all columns. Prepare the final output.**

```
df3$DE <- apply(df3[, c("V1", "V2", "V3")], 1, paste, collapse = " | ")
df4 <- df3[, "DE", drop = FALSE] 

df4
#                               DE
# 1 Europa | Deutschland | München
# 2      Europa | England | London
# 3  Europa | Deutschland | Berlin
# 4     Europa | Italien | Venedig
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- data.frame("DE" = c("Europa | Deutschland | München", "Europa | England | London", "Europa | Germany | Berlin ", "Europa | Italy | Venedig"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame("GE" = c("Deutschland", "Italien", "England"), 
                  "EN" = c("Germany", "Italy", "UK"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```